# android: customized dialog - round corners and customized background

Tags: android, xml, dialog, customization

### dialog layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/blue" />

    <stroke
        android:width="7dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />

    <corners android:radius="35px" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

</shape>
```

Question:

The above code simply makes a round cornered dialog filled with solid blue color.
I would like to ask how could the above be modified so that the dialog still has round corners but with a customized png as background, instead of a solid color?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a layer-list to do it there. More info: [Layer-list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

or declare the imageview inside a layout with your shape as background and no colour

Comment: I am now already using in my layout `android:background="@drawable/layout_round_corners_white_boarder_fill_candies"` and so...how to add the background to the shape..